# How to build OpenCV (2.4.5) with OpenNI2 on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, openni

I have some difficulties to link OpenNi on Visual studio 2012. I linked OpenCv on VS2012 successfully but, when I add the properties (Add_Includes, add_library, ..) to the project, it doesn't work.

I tried (CV_CAP_OPENNI) with no result.

Any one can help, do I have to build OpenCV with OpenNI or just a problem o link ?
thanks.

Comment: OpenCV can not be compiled with OpenNI 2.0. You may want to get OpenNI 1.5 or check [this post](http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/opencvkinect-acquiring-kinect-data.html) which describes a method to use OpenNI2 with OpenCV